# I'm having problems trying to correct a conversion issue in sql server 2016

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a case statement where I'm trying to SUM multiple column int values and then  format the summed value to '00000015700+' as an example but getting a conversion error in SQL Server 2016.

Here is the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '00000015700+' to
>   data type int.

Here is my code :

```
CASE
    WHEN x.Code = 'WRITPREM' AND x.[Description] = 'NEW POLICY' THEN RIGHT('00000000000' + CAST(REPLACE((sum(x.totalPolicy_BIN) + sum(x.totalPolicy_COL) + sum(x.totalPolicy_OTC) + sum(x.totalPolicy_PDM) + sum(x.totalPolicy_MED) +sum(x.totalPolicy_PIP) + sum(x.totalPolicy_REN) + sum(x.totalPolicy_TOW) + sum(x.totalPolicy_UBI) + sum(x.totalPolicy_UPD)),'.','') as varchar(12)) + '+',12)END as TEST
```

Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You will need to supply more information. The table structure that your query against and some sample data. What is the data type of the columns you are adding. Also supply the whole query as it could be something else that is causing the issue

Comment: You have reversed the `REPLACE` and `CAST` commands. You should `CAST` the value to string, then `REPLACE` the decimal point and add your plus sign to the end, then take the `RIGHT(..., 12)` of that value.  Also, QUESTION: Do you really want to merge the value after the decimal point with the number, or do you want to truncate the value at the decimal point? Both are valid methods of handling the numbers, but I just want to make sure that you really want the post decimal digits included.

Comment: @LaughingVergil, thank you for your help.  That was the answer.  Appreciate your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

One of the fields that you are `sum()`ing contains the value with a "+" sign.  As a result, SQL Server cannot convert the value to an integer in order to `sum()`.  It seems you are applying the function on a non-numeric column(s).  So you have unexpected data in at least one of those columns.  Try eliminating some of the `sum()` columns to figure out which column contains the offending data.  Ideally, you'd have the correct data types on each column and not run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have reversed the REPLACE and CAST commands. You should CAST the value to string, then REPLACE the decimal point and add your plus sign to the end, then take the RIGHT(..., 12) of that value.